# Does Materialize CSS framework have a "container-fluid" equivalent?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am creating a website for a friends band, and I decided it'd be a good time to learn a new mobile first framework.

One of the biggest things I see bands doing is adding full width images ([example](http://www.mumfordandsons.com/home/)), and I remembered reading [this article](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/bootstrap-3-tips-and-tricks-you-might-not-know#dont-forget-container-fluid-for-full-width-rows) about full-width rows in Bootstrap, and searched through [Materialize's](http://materializecss.com/grid.html) grid documentation, to no avail.

What I need is a way to create this "full width" row, ideally without breaking responsiveness. From my understanding, Bootstrap utilizes padding & margins in "container-fluid" (e.g., `width: 100%;`, `padding: 0;` `margin: -15px;`, where `body` I believe has a `margin: 15px; padding: 15px;`), which easily allows for the full-width rows, but Materiallize does not. Any help would be greatly appreciated, my design skills are not the best!

Comment: The demo on the page you linked to show's full-width content? Simply turn containers off...

Comment: hi, i had this problem a while back. if I understand correctly, you want your image to span the full width of the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also do something like

```
.container{
            width: 100%;
            max-width:initial;
            > .row{
                margin: 0;
                > .col{
                    padding: 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

in your scss.

Here's the example:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.col {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width:initial;
}
.container > .row {
  margin: 0;
}
.container > .row > .col {
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      This div is 12-columns wide on all screen sizes
    </div>
    <div class="col s6 yellow">6-columns (one-half)</div>
    <div class="col s6 blue">6-columns (one-half)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      This div is 12-columns wide on all screen sizes
    </div>
   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Here is a [pen](http://codepen.io/h3xc0ntr0l/pen/KzYKGy) of the "full-width" row I was able to implement. Sorry about all the angular stuff and other sloppiness. It's a somewhat big project (there are the barebones of a CMS on an admin page for them) and I didn't have time to go through and take out all the irrelevant stuff.

Well, as of right now, I believe I have found a solution. I'll give others a chance to test and answer

```
<div class="full-width">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1900/400/" class="responsive-img"/>
  <div class="full-width-content">
    <h3> We are Kokopelli </h3>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- I don't know how well this solution will work if I want to add
more than one full width column, but for now it worked -->
<main class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="schedule col l8 ">
      <h3> Schedule </h3>
....
</main>
```

Where my scss is as follows

```
.full-width{
  max-width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  .full-width-content{
    position: absolute
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your image to span the full width of the screen: As such, here is a simple an intuitive method to do so:

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "image">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col s12">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the **CSS**:

```
.image {
    background-image: url("");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*background-color: #2B2931;*/
    height: 80vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

The benefit of this method is you get all the responsiveness needed for your content, and you also implement the container-width for your text.

Comment: Thank you! It will be quite awhile before I can actually test this, but the css + markup makes absolute sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using the grid system in [Materialize CSS](https://materializecss.com/) will give you an equivalent of `container-fluid` in [Bootstrap CSS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/#fluid-containers) consider the following example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l12 xl12">
      <h3>Fluid container</h3>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum ex nostrum odit quis debitis? Iure incidunt soluta adipisci suscipit ut debitis facilis maxime, velit laborum delectus asperiores cum, minus corporis!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```